# Finding confidence intervals in a R generated sample

Tags: confidence-interval

Having this

```
pob1<-rchisq(90,12)
```

How can I estimate the expected value and variance of this sample? How do I find the 95% and 99% confidence intervals of the sample for the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need not *estimate* the expected value and variance of a given sample. Since we have the data from the sample, we can exactly calculate the expected value and variance.

The expected value of the sample will just be the sample mean: $\bar{x}=\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n}$

The variance of the sample will just be the sample variance: $s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\Sigma (x_i - \bar{x})$

These statistics, the sample mean and sample variance, are estimates of the population mean and population variance but are exact calculations (not estimates) of the sample mean and sample variance.

Since you know exactly what your sample mean and sample variance are, you need not construct a confidence interval for these. If you'd like to construct a confidence interval for the population mean or population variance, there are formulas available depending on which you are interested in finding.

The formula for a 95%/99% confidence interval of the population mean will be $\bar{x} \pm t* \times \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, $s$ is the sample standard deviation, $n$ is the size of your sample, and $t*$ is the critical value of the $t$-distribution which can be found online based on your sample size $n$ and what level of confidence (95%/99%) you want.